# Can we implement goroutine in the goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm using goroutines in the function because I want when the function will start then the quires of database also run on that time. But there is a question I'm asking that Can we implement a goroutine in the other goroutine because in the function I already set a go routine but in that go routine there are to queries more and I want that they also run when the parent goroutine starts. Example

```
func main(){
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(){
       defer wg.Done()
       Id,err := QueryWhichWillReturnId()
       if err == nil{
           wg.Add(1)
           go func(){
               defer wg.Done()
               data:= GetAnyDataById(Id)
               fmt.Println(data)
           }()
       }
    }()
  wg.Wait()
}
```

Is this above example is possible while implementing goroutines?

any suggestions will appreciated.

Comment: Except for the strange formatting, the code looks fine to me. You just need to call `wg.Wait()` somewhere.

Comment: @RolandIllig yes but this is a example that I'm showing thanks for that

Comment: Yes you can, did you run into some problem when you tried it, or did you not actually try it?

Answer (score 1):

goroutine can be start from a parant goroutine.Once goroutineB starts from goroutineA, they runs the same weigh.

There are a thing for you to consider if you want to do like this.

Is my new goroutine neccessary to start?

I give you an example that  a query request need to be saved both to database and a remote log server. Two saving steps are parallel and no interference. Then it's good to start 2 goroutine. One to save to database, one to save to log server.Now you look at your query. `GetAnyDataById(Id)` ,apparantly your new routine query depends on your former query result form `QueryWhichWillReturnId()`, are they none-interfere? are they logical parallel? Neither, so this is a bad spot to use goroutine.

Last, you `wg.Add(1)`, but you `wg.Done()` twice, it will panic.

Can we implement a goroutine inside a goroutine?
yes. you can use `go func(){}()` wherever you want to start a new goroutine.

```golang
func main(){
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(){
       defer wg.Done()
       Id,err := QueryWhichWillReturnId()
       if err != nil{
           fmt.Println(err.Error())
           return
       }
       data:= GetAnyDataById(Id)
       fmt.Println(data)
    }()
  wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: you mean to the `defer wg.Done()` I have called twice and it will return me a pannic?

Comment: @puneet55667788 you didn't finish `wg.Wait()`.the panic might escape because the main stops and your goroutine're hence forcely dead

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the word "implement" is not accurate. `go` is a keyword in Go language which is used before a Go function call to start a goroutine asynchronous. So you can start a goroutine almost anywhere with a valid Go function.

Only when a function is called with `go` before it, it's viewed as a goroutine. Otherwise, it's just a normal function.